# Migrating Analytics from Old application to new application in Apigee

Tags: apigee, apigee-baas

We had to delete an application and create new application with same attributes as old application. Is there any way that we can transfer analytics of old application to new application in Apigee?

Tried creating new application and deleting old application.

Analytics of old application is not lost. But would like to know if there is way to transfer analytics from one app to other app.

Thanks.

Comment: There is management API to retrieve the analytics, but there are no APIs to create one. The analytics data are obtained at runtime from the traffic to your API. It does not make sense to create it manually.
One option is to use a 3rd party tools such as Splunk or Elasticsearch to store your analytics and fetch them as needed.